# Sort related bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig script which generated a relation

```
A: {x: chararray,B: {(y: chararray,z: int)}}
```

I want to sort A based on B.y, however the following piece gives me error:

> Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near z

```
output = foreach A{
    sorted = order B by z DSC;
    generate x,sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use DESC instead of DSC.

e.g.

```
output = foreach A{
    sorted = order B by z DESC;
    generate x,sorted;
}
```