# Sort a bag with pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following structure

```
GROUPED_ANSWERS_PARENT_ID: {group: chararray,ANSWERS: {(id: chararray,score: long,parentId: chararray)}}
```

My data where score is respectively 27,287,35,37,46,48

```
((4,{(305467,27,4),(7,287,4),(2791,35,4),(594436,37,4),(110198,46,4),(7263,48,4)}))
```

I want it to be ordered by score DESC and return the following:

```
((4,{(7,287,4),(7263,48,4),(110198,46,4),(594436,37,4),(2791,35,4),(305467,27,4)}))
```

I have tried the following but the result is still incorrect.

```
SORTED_GROUPED_ANSWERS_PARENT_ID = FOREACH GROUPED_ANSWERS_PARENT_ID {
   ORDER_BY_SCORE =  ORDER $1 BY score;
   GENERATE (group,ORDER_BY_SCORE);
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144194/sorting-a-bag-in-pig), but it did not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the DESC keyword

```
SORTED_GROUPED_ANSWERS_PARENT_ID = FOREACH GROUPED_ANSWERS_PARENT_ID 
                         {
                                   ORDER_BY_SCORE =  ORDER ANSWERS BY score DESC;
                                   GENERATE (group,ORDER_BY_SCORE);
                         };
```